# WinObjC indows VM vsimporter not supported

Tags: windows, winobjc

When I run `vsimporter` on my Windows VM 10 command line (cmd.exe) I have a message telling me the following

> This application cannot be executed on your PC

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What's your question, though?

Comment: a solution to this problem

Comment: May you the user logged in does not have permission to run the command. Instead, try running the command as `administrator`.

Comment: I am a director, see window header in the image.